# 2d hsv color space in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to reproduce this graph in matplotlib (taken from wikipedia)

[image]

basically a 2d hsv color space where saturation is set to 1.0. here's what I have done so far

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import outer

x = outer(arange(0, 1, 0.01), ones(100))

imshow(transpose(x), cmap=cm.hsv)
show()
```

this plots the hue channel but I don't know how to add a second channel.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to create the HSV array and convert it to RGB, here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb

V, H = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:300j]
S = np.ones_like(V)
HSV = np.dstack((H,S,V))
RGB = hsv_to_rgb(HSV)
pl.imshow(RGB, origin="lower", extent=[0, 360, 0, 1], aspect=150)
pl.xlabel("H")
pl.ylabel("V")
pl.title("$S_{HSV}=1$")
pl.show()
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: What's the idea behind the complex numbers `100j` and `300j`?

Comment: Ah got it. From the numpy docs: "However, if the step length is a complex number (e.g. 5j), then the integer part of its magnitude is interpreted as specifying the number of points to create between the start and stop values, where the stop value is inclusive."