# Is there any way to manipulate an image using a color curve in python?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have a series of tif images and was wondering if there is a possibility to write something in python (using maybe scikit-image or OpenCV) to apply a color curve. The data I have looks like the following, where we have a list of x, y, x, y... data like so: (0, 0, 32, 22, 64, 56, 128, 128, 192, 196, 255, 255).

[image]

Comment: See cv2.lut. Example usage at https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/

Comment: @nathancy That might work if I can create a custom ColorMap.

Comment: Yes you can [create your own heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new information you provided I think that the following code should do the trick. `lut_in` is the vector of input gray levels and `lut_out` the desired output level. Here it's applied for all 3 channels (like in photoshop). The only thing you need is the interpolation to have a LUT (look up table) of 256 elements, that fits the 256 gray levels of the input. You can apply the same method for other color resolutions.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('apple.jpg')

lut_in = [0, 127, 255]
lut_out = [0, 80, 255]

lut_8u = np.interp(np.arange(0, 256), lut_in, lut_out).astype(np.uint8)
image_contrasted = cv2.LUT(image, lut_8u)

cv2.imwrite('apple_dark.jpg', image_contrasted)
```

Input:
[image]
Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this with python PIL instead of OpenCV just in case anyone stumbles upon this answer as I did and doesn't want to use OpenCV.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("apple.png").convert("RGBA")                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
lut_x = [0, 127, 180, 255]                                                  
lut_y = [5, 80, 90, 255]                                                    
                                                                            
lut_u8 = np.interp(np.arange(0, 256), lut_x, lut_y).astype(np.uint8)        
                                                                            
R, G, B, A = [0, 1, 2, 3]                                                   
source = im.split()                                                         
out = []                                                                    
for band in [R, G, B]:                                                      
    out.append(source[band].point(lut_u8))                                  
out.append(source[A]) # Dont use LUT on the alpha band                      
                                                                            
merged_img = Image.merge('RGBA', out)                                       
merged_img.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, some already gave answers on how to apply a color LUT to an image. However when I read your question, I have the impression that you would like to have in fact a 2D colormap, where the color depends on two parameters. If this is the case, I would recommend to visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626482/how-can-i-add-a-2d-colorbar-or-a-color-wheel-to-matplotlib) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966600/matplotlib-colormap-with-two-parameter/41967868#41967868).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx, I added an image to make it clearer. The list of numbers represents the points in the curve.