OCR with varying background colors and low contrasts?
I'm trying to convert images to text using pytesseract. It works well for images with white background and black text, but it fails for images with less contrast and varying colors.
I have tried to put together all situations into one image. In most situations, the text and background each has a single color. What image processing would you recommend for the image below? Is there some kind of "local high contrast" conversion that could be used?
Edit: The image is representative of the images I will be processing, with regards to colors. With regards to text, some texts will be longer. I try to locate data on screenshots of webpages.
Code:
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

img = PIL.Image.open('ocrtest.png')
ocr_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, timeout=30)
print(ocr_string)

Result:
Test one

Test five

Test 6 (not as important)


I have played around with curves in Gimp and found the equivalent using numpy. I've had some success with subsets of the image, but it does not solve the generic problem.
# Points found using Curve tool in gimp
# Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279250/106019
lut_x = [226, 229]
lut_y = [  0, 252]
import numpy as np
lut_u8 = np.interp(np.arange(0, 256), lut_x, lut_y).astype(np.uint8)
R, G, B, A = [0, 1, 2, 3]
source = img.split()
out = []
for band in [R, G, B]:
    out.append(source[band].point(lut_u8))
out.append(source[A])
merged_img = PIL.Image.merge('RGBA', out)



I haven't used pytesseract before but if you use Pytroch, you can train a convolutional neural network to recognize characters. Postal services often use similar techniques since letters are processed automatically and even small models can deal with bad handwriting and general noise. There are even pre-trained models that do fairly well on the MNIST dataset (letters and numbers). You can add variations of colored text and background to the dataset instead of using black and white images.

Isn't it what tesserarct already is? A use of a already trained model?

yes but tesseract has ancient baggage to it that ruins the model's performance. that is, for example, thresholding the input and picking connected components (glyphs, hopefully) to present to the model. those two actions alone ruin its performance on "tricky" inputs that the model itself would easily succeed on. -- yes, any OCR based on custom pytorch models would have to do something smarter than thresholding and connected components.

Tesseract needs binarisation to work. That is to have a black and white image.
If given image is not already binarized, otsu's is used by default. But that is a global binarisation. It does not works well in context where background and foreground color are different in different blocks.
I am not sure whether your image is just a torture test you used to try to find optimal parameters. Or if it is a realistic example of what you may encounter.
If it is the first, be aware that putting all those examples in a single image make the problem more difficult.
If it is the second, then, it would be interesting to know how representative is this example. Will there always be some rectangle area with text in it?
Because, in the second case, the more appropriate answer may be to try to isolate each rectangle first, and run tesseract separately (with correct psm) in each rectangle.
But, well, a generic answer could be that you need a local binarisation technique.
There are some, well known (niblack, sauvaula,...)
I've just tried both, they won't work in all cases. But they are made for real world image.
In your case, with such image, we can fabricate our own local segmentation method. Based on the fact that regions are locally made of 2 colors, and the dominant one is the background. So, if I extract a local window somewhere, and compute the median color in it, that median is the background (because more than half of the pixels is background). So text is what is very different from the background
Hence a binarisation:
img = np.asarray(PIL.Image.open('ocrtest.png'))
bw=img.mean(axis=2)
bwloc=np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(bw, (15,15))
back = np.median(bwloc, axis=(2,3))
binar = np.abs(bw[7:-7,7:-7]-back)<30

I work on grayscale image (the bw=img.mean... could also have read directly the image in grayscale with PIL). bwloc is a 4D array, containg for each pixel a subwindow of 15x15 pixels. So back is the median of each of those local 15x15 window. That is the background. Binarized images is an image that is white (True) fox pixels that are close enough (30) to the background, and black for those that are very different from the background (tesseract expects black on white text).
Note that the background is computed on 15x15 local subwindows. And we compare it to the raw value of pixel in the middle of that, hence the 7s shift. And the fact that we can do that for the pixels that are less than 7 pixels from a borderof the image.
The binarized image is

Then, another thing you need to do (if we want to use tesseract on this image of local text. It would be done differently if we extracted rectangles first) is to choose a correct psm. Default one expect some page of text, like from a book.
Here, psm 11 seems the more correct (sparse text)
Which is done this way
ocr_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(binar, timeout=30, config="--psm 12")

Result as is is
Test one

Test 6 (not as important)

Test two

Test?

Test &

Test three

Test 9

Test four

Test 10

Test five

Not perfect. There are some confusion between 7 and ?; and between 8 and &.
But I guess that the limit of the test. We would need real text to decide how to avoid those. For example by using restricted charset to force tesseract to choose a digit.
My homemade segmentation algorithm could also certainly be improved. For example, I grayscaled the image first and segmented later. Which I usually rant a lot about "we shouldn't do that", because that is ignoring color information, that may be interesting (a red on green text could be invisible if that red and green have the same grayscale intensity).
And I haven't tried that hard to make Sauvola works before reinventing the wheel with my local median.

Thank you! I have to play around a bit with this. Running your example on my original images, it is very close to correct, but some words have been wrongly detected (e.g. "bail" -> "bait"). Excuse my ignorance, but how can I display the result of binar graphically? I tried PIL.Image.merge('L', binar).show().   Background: I am trying to locate information on screenshots of webpages - I think about 4 of each "test" appear in each image and I want my algorithm to be general. So I expect these areas of one text color and one background color.

binar is a boolean array. Which match PIL mode 1, not L. Plus, merge is to be used with PIL Images, and binar is just the array. So, I would PIL.Image.fromarray(binar).show() to show binar with PIL.

as an alternative to those stride tricks, I'd recommend looking into skimage and OpenCV. both have median filters for this purpose.

I played around a bit with skimage and came up with this: https://pastebin.com/exfeutY1   https://imgur.com/a/VOc1M1W  It correctly recognizes all texts except Test 9 and adds some extra letters. I tried to sharpen the text a bit because I think the "blobiness" messes up some text in my original images.

Note: In the "manual" algorithm, I got problems with black spots between letters for larger fonts. I tried turning up the window size to 20x20, but then processing became really slow.

New idea: Is it possible to split the image based on the boundaries of the rectangles? Maybe using the median color calculation to get one-colored rectangles. Then I can feed each rectangle with text into tesseract. I think that any page I will look at will have texts that do not cross rectangle boundaries.
