# python, how to generate a normally distributed set of RGB colors

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors

I would like to sample RGB or HSV colors interpolating from green to blue. However, I want that the mean of the gaussian should be green so that the majority of the set will be dominated by greenish colors. In the end, I want to achieve that when you interpolate from green to blue or red, you start deviating from the crowd. Something like this but the majority should be green..

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you're plotting data have a read of the reasoning behind the new default colormaps in matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html

Comment: I need data samples in RGB or other color format which fit the distribution i described above.

Comment: Doesn't the ``cmap=cm.jet`` colorbar has its mean at green? So ``cmap(val)`` where val is your sample drawn from gaussian distribution should return what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the HSV color space, for which pure green is at H=120 degrees. You can create a bivariate normal distribution in H-V space of `num` points centered about a `mean` and distributed according to the covariance matrix `cov`:

```
import numpy as np

num = 1000
mean = [120,0.5] # [hue,value] 
cov = [[20,0],[0,0.01]]
hv = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,num)
```

Next, we modulo the matrix so that points beyond the boundaries are looped back in:

```
hv[:,0] %= 360
hv[:,1] %= 1
```

Next, we borrow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787103/2d-hsv-color-space-in-matplotlib) to create an RGB map in HS space (V=1):

```
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V, H = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:300j]

S = np.ones_like(V)
HSV = np.dstack((H,S,V))
RGB = hsv_to_rgb(HSV)

plt.imshow(RGB, origin="lower", extent=[0, 360, 0, 1], aspect=150)
```

Finally, overlay our distribution onto H-S space:

```
plt.scatter(hv[:,0],hv[:,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]
You can play around with `cov` to achieve the desired distribution. For example, `cov = [[80,0.7],[0.1,0.006]]` gives us

[image]

Also, you can easily extend this example to three dimensions to consider changes in saturation.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the following.
You would first need a colormap which has green in its center. If none of the available [standard colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) works for you, you can built your own colormap. In the simplest case, it would consist of three colors (blue, green, red)

```
colors = ["blue", "green", "red"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("name", colors)
```

You can then use a normalization instance with its center at the center of the normal distribution. Here we choose it to be at 0; therefore the normalization limits need to be symmetrical about zero.

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-3, vmax=3)
```

Now, having a normal distributed variable `x` you may sample from the colormap as

```
sample = cmap(norm(x))
```

In order to plot this, find a complete example below:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


n = 600
x = np.random.normal(size=n)
y = np.random.rand(n)

colors = ["blue", "green", "red"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("name", colors)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-3, vmax=3)
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(6,3), 
      gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[1,3]}, sharex=True)
ax.axis("off")
ax.hist(x, bins=21, edgecolor="k")
sc = ax2.scatter(x,y,s=15, c=x, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax2)
cax = fig.colorbar(sc, ax=ax)
cax.ax.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what does the y-axis signify?

Comment: The y axis is just used to stretch the points out in space. If they were all on a line, you wouldn't be able to distinguish them anymore. The relevant dimension is the x dimension, which is coded in space and color according to the colormap.